# Eclipse java find attribute value

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have this html code

```
<div pagesequence="46" pagename="page0003">
```

how can i drive the value of *pagename* with the help of *pagesequence*?

i have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[pagesequence='46']").           );
```

What do I use to get the value of the *pagename* attributed, i.e: `page0003`.

Comment: Java, you mean javascript ?, please rewrite your question

Comment: no, not java. I am writing it in Eclipse using java

Comment: Are you using selenium ?

Comment: yes this is in selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@pagesequence='46']"));
String pagename = element.getAttribute("pagename");
System.out.println(pagename);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below. This should work

```
List<WebElements> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@pagesequence='46']"));
elements.get(0).getAttribute("pagename");
```

Comment: Ita not working. Here a am trying to get output "pagename" value.  I think you get my question wrong.

Comment: ok just replace the getAttribute. Updated the answer. If it is still not working then is it giving any error?

Comment: Just click on the correct image(its actually a right mark) on the left side of my answer. And you can also give upvote by clicking the uparrow beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[pagesequence='46']")).getAttribute("pagename");
```